# Why doesn't text-shadow support spared radius?

Tags: css, flutter

The `box-shadow` has `spread-radius`, but I do not understand why it is not only in `text-shadow`.

According to the link attached to [**MDN**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds/#box-shadow), there is only description of `sparead-radius`.

looking at [`text-shadow`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor/#text-shadow-property), it is the same as `box-shadow`,
BUT, there is an only explanation that inset and spread-radius are not included!!!

Not just css, but also flutter!!!!
This is a [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Shadow-class.html) of the shadow class used when shadowing text in flutter.

I want to know why text shadow does not support spread radius. I wish someone could provide me with related materials or explanations.

Comment: because it's not easy to implement, the same for drop-shadow but it will be available in the future https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-4/#text-shadow-property

Comment: @TemaniAfif 
I'm not sure where what you said is contained in that link. about future support too. Could you please give me a quote if it's okay with you?

Comment: that link is the new Spec of text-shadow, read it and you will see that it has changed. I have no idea when it will get supported but it will be in the *future* since it's already in the Specification

Comment: @TemaniAfif 

It's the last one. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

The CSS syntax for the text-shadow property is:
text-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur-radius color|none|initial|inherit;

where:
h-shadow - horizontal offset of shadow
v-shadow - vertical offset of shadow
blur-radius - The blur radius
color - color of the shadow

Unlike text-shadow, the box-shadow has an additional property called the spread distance/radius which comes after the blur-radius and can be set to inset.

Comment: I wonder **why** the spread radius supported by box shadow is not supported by text shadow.

Comment: The spread-radius in the box-shadow increases the size of the shadow. In texts, it may disturb other text elements.